# How to execute shell script which contains python execution from php apache server?

Tags: php, python, shell, image-processing

.php file :

```
<?php
shell_exec('./magic.sh');
?>
```

magic.sh file :

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/my_virtualenv/
source bin/activate
cd ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
python3 mypythonfile.py
```

First two lines are to enter in the virtual environment and the next two for python execution.
The magic.sh file alone works fine when executed from the terminal, executable permissions are also granted.

I get no output, no error just the blank screen on the web browser.

Is there any other method for my .php file to execute the python code which i am using to process the images with openCV, it stores the processed images in a folder created in "htdocs" itself. I want to display these processed images on my .php webpage.

Comment: any error generated or what ? what happens after running above code ?

Comment: Is your webserver running with under the same login? In `magic.sh` the `~` refers to your `$HOME`, that might be a different one. And will the webserver know where to find `python3`?

Comment: I believed entering the virtual environment should enable the localhost server to find the packages. I am not sure how the web server is working here.

Comment: @WalterA I understood what you mean. When I "open terminal" through the xampp interface, In the terminal  it says : `root@debian:~# `  , webserver is not running under the same login. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment you say your webserver is not running under the root account. Please do not change it, running your webserver as `nobody` is the first security measure protecting your server.
You will need a script that the webserver user can run.
Your current `magic.sh` will not work, when the root folders `.virtualenvs` and `.bitnami` are protected as they should be.
Copy the necessary files to the webserver-user environment, use a full path to python3 ans see what else you are missing.
Try to `su` to the webserver user and try the `modified_magic.sh`.

I thought about telling you about the `setuid` giving `nobody` elevated rights, but this will cause serious security risks. So now you know there is a zombie out there, don't let him in.

Comment: I was using xampp vm, it was working on a Linux-based virtual machine from which I couldn't access my own files, I would've had to again install all the packages there too. Instead I installed normal 'xampp' and now basic python command works and are echoed. But I am still not able to process the images like i did by executing the commands through terminal. I am expecting the `shell_exec('./magic.sh');` to work as if i am executing `./magic.sh` command in my terminal. In the python file I am taking input from one folder and storing the processed images in another.